# get list of external stages used by a storage integration

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In our Snowflake deployment we have a storage integration that I *think* is not being used and would like to delete.

My understanding, correct me if I'm wrong, is that if a storage integration isn't being used by any external stages, it would be safe to delete.

Assuming this is the case, is there some sort of SQL that can be run to get a list of all external stages used by a storage integration, to ensure that the list is empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RESULT_SCAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan) table function to get the result you need after using `show stages` command

The following will give you the list of external stages which are not used in a storage integration, you can tweak the query to meet your needs.

```
show stages
;
select "name"
from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
where "type" = 'EXTERNAL'
and "storage_integration" is null
;
```

Note that because the output column names from the DESC or SHOW commands were generated in lowercase, the commands use delimited identifier notation (double quotes) around the column names in the query to ensure that the column names in the query match the column names in the output that was scanned.

Comment: My question was actually slightly different - I wanted to get all stages with a *particular* storage integration - but I can modify your suggested query to do that. Thank you!